# Angular currency pipe show with given format

Tags: angular, pipe

I want to apply the currency pipe to get the required output format:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <div id="price">{{price | currency:myCurr: '9.2-2'}}</div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    price = 623.56;
    myCurr = 'EUR';
}
```

My expected output is €000,000,623.56, but I am getting as 9.2-2312.56

Comment: According to [the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#parameters), the second parameter is `display`. not the `digitsInfo`. So, you can try something like this: `{{price | currency : myCurr : 'code' : '9.2-2'}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks you forget to add 'symbol' to your template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
            <div id="price">{{price | currency:myCurr:'symbol':'9.2-2'}}</div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    price = 623.56;
    myCurr = 'EUR';
}
```